# Is the diagram commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

In the following diagram $f,g$ are isomorphisms and $\pi, \tau$ are canonical projections. Is the diagram then commutative ?

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{ll}
A & \ra{g} &B \\
\da{\pi} & &\da{\tau}\\A' & \ra{f} &B'
\end{array}
$$

($A, B$ are groups) What if $\pi$ and $\tau$ are just surjective ?

Answer (score 1):

No! take: $A,B,A',B'=\mathbb{Z}$ observe that here $\pi$ and $\tau$ are trivial projections. and take $g= id$ and $$f:A' \to B' \\ x\mapsto -x$$ then your claim is wrong since $f\neq g=id$

For your claim to work you need quite precise $f,g$ and quotients, since they heavily depend on each other, also observe that the above example decends to any quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ with more than $2$ elements.

Also, regarding your last question: every surjection is isomorphic to a quotient, hence that does not change a thing (although this crashes in general either way)

Comment: maybe the projection should be nontrivial.  When for instance $A=Z/27Z,\  B=F_{27},\  A'=Z/3Z,\  B'=F_3$

Comment: Same counterexample still works. It only does not if you quotient out $2\mathbb{Z}$.
to be more precise, take the groups you proposed, and take f and g, just like I defined them (they are not at all dependent on $\mathbb{Z}$, and the counterexample only relies on the fact that you have a group where elements are not self inverse) and the diagram will still commute.

Comment: sorry, emant of course: not commute!